# How to validate the content of a textbox in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, kendo-ui, requiredfieldvalidator

I use Kendo UI MVC4 in my project. My ProductItem.cshtml in View is :

```
<form class="k-content" id="ticketsForm">
    <ul class="edit-form">
        <li>
            <label for="Name" class="required">Name:</label>
            @Html.TextBox("Name", ViewData["Name"] ?? string.Empty)




        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="Price">Price:</label> @Html.TextBox("Price", ViewData["Price"] ?? string.Empty)
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="Quantity">Quantity:</label> @Html.TextBox("Quantity", ViewData["Quantity"] ?? string.Empty)
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="ExpiredDate">ExpiredDate:</label>
            @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
              .Name("ExpiredDate")
              .Value("08/06/2015")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:150px" })
            )
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

I want to validate textbox but I don't know how. Can someone helps me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest re-constructing your objects. Rather than adding the values in ViewData, you can consider using Models and add validators on the models.

Please refer to the [post](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model)

Comment: @scvn80 please mark the reply as the answer. Glad this was of help